# Error al pasar mis datos a SVR y SVC

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Tengo un problema con mi código: Quiero utilizar el método `SVR` de Sklearn pero marca un error diciendo que 'SVR' no es un objeto llamable cuando uso la función `SVR()`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
```

Así es como utilizo la función `SVR` y los parámetros que le doy:

```
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poli = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree = 2)
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
```

Así es como me marca el error:

> ```
> <ipython-input-1-6f926795cb9b> in prediccion(fechas, precios, x)
>
>     24     svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)
>     25 
>     26     svr_lin(fechas, precios) <----
>     27     svr_poli(fechas, precios)
>     28     svr_rbf(fechas, precios)
>
> TypeError: 'SVR' object is not callable
> ```

También sucede lo mismo si quiero utilizar SVC en vez de SVR.
No sé a que se deba y espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

[`sklearn.svm.SVR`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn-svm-svr) (Support Vector Regression) no es una función, es una clase, por lo que `svr_lin`, `svr_poly` y `svr_rbf` son instancias de `sklearn.svm.SVR`.

Cuando haces `svr_lin(fechas, precios)` estás llamando al objeto e intentando pasar dos argumentos, pero como muestra la excepción las instancias de `sklearn.svm.SVR`  no son "callables" dado que no implementan el método `__call__`.

Supongo que estas intentando entrenar el modelo siendo `fechas` el vector de entrenamiento y `precios` los valores diana, en tal caso lo que debes usar es el método [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR.fit) de la instancia, no llamar a la misma:

```
svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)
svr_poli = SVR(kernel='poly', C=1e3, degree = 2)
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1)

svr_lin.fit(fechas, precios) 
svr_poli.fit(fechas, precios)
svr_rbf.fit(fechas, precios)
```

Exactamente lo mismo se aplica a [`sklearn.svm.SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)